# GitHub pages defaulting to a randomly generated name instead of <whatever>.github.io

Tags: github-pages

I'm working in a repo I created under an organizational GitHub

When I publish the repo via GitHub pages the URL defaults to a randomly generated string, such as

`http(s)://windy-waterfalls-e5r23og9.pages.github.io/`

I'd like it to default to `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<repository>` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io/<repository>` so that the URL is explanatory of the repo, and so I don't have to pay/manage my own domain

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The gh-pages url depends on the repo name for the url. Have you checked https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site

Comment: Yea, if I make a repo that's not under the organizational GitHub the name defaults to ```https://testore.github.io/test-repo/``` for example.

The issue only occurs under the organizational GitHub and I can't find any docs related to default URL settings; only for using a completely custom domain

Comment: If your GitHub pages site is configured to be private, the domain will be such randomly generated one. See https://docs.github.com/ja/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/changing-the-visibility-of-your-github-pages-site

Answer (score 4):

This occurs when the gh pages **visibility is set to private**

According to [About subdomains for privately published sites](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/changing-the-visibility-of-your-github-pages-site)

> Privately published sites are available at a different subdomain than publicly published sites. This ensures that your GitHub Pages site is secure from the moment it's published.
>
> We use a unique subdomain for the privately published site to ensure that other repositories in your organization cannot publish content on the same origin as the site

According to [Organization-level custom domain not working for internal repository pages #23350](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23350)

> For security reasons, private Pages sites (the ones with a random default hostname that enforce authentication + authorization on access) need to be isolated.

### Workarounds

1. If the info **isn't sensitive**, you can go to Settings > Set the Visibility to Public
2. You can still set a custom domain to avoid having a long set of garbled characters in your URL